# get average using linq and EF6 C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm using EF6, and I have EmployeeAttendance table that I want to get average of total working hour for every employee in this table using Linq.

### Date    | CheckIn | CheckOut  | Employee_ID

### 16/9/2018 | 09:40   | 16:26     |  2

### 17/9/2018 | 09:25   | 16:31     |  2

### 18/9/2018 | 09:46   | 16:18     |  2

### 19/9/2018 | 10:14   | 16:18     |  2

Comment: Define average please. Average per day? Average per entry? Are dates unique? And MVC is totally irrelevant to the question - the resulting LINQ query is a floating number or double, what you then do with it is NOT part of the question.

Comment: Average per entry ,dates not unique, and result will be floating number i think

Comment: What do your types look like on the SQL side?  I'm assuming Employee_ID is an int?  Is Date a SQL `Date` or a SQL `DateTime`?  What about CheckIn and CheckOut?

Comment: Average per date from `16/9/2018` to `19/9/2018`,dates not unique, and result will be floating number i think

Comment: @Flydog57 Employee_ID is an int Date is an string ,CheckIn and CheckOut are stings

Comment: Why strings? That's a big step in the wrong direction. Why not `DateTime`? Also, what did you try? It's not clear to me why you're asking this. Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please add all your comment explanations to your question by editing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the `Employee` with a certain `Id` has a sequence of `EmployeeAttendances`, where every `EmployeeAttendance` has a value of `EmployeeId` equal to the `Id` of the `Employee` that it belongs to.

Every `EmployeeAttendance` has a `Checkin` time and a `CheckOut` time. You forgot to tell us the type of it, so I'll assume it is something similar to `DateTime.TimeOfDay`. What is important that you can subtract two of these times, resulting in a `TimeSpan`.

Let's define the TimeSpan between CheckIn and Checkout as the `Shift`

You can run in several problems that you didn't specify:

- You specified that an `Employee` can have several `Checkins` and `Checkouts` on a day. Can these times overlap?
- What if an `Employee` checks in on one day and Checksout the next day?
- What if an `Employee` checks in, but doesn't checkout at all?
- What if an `Employee` doesn't Checkin/Checkout on a certain day? Does that count as zero in the average, or shouldn't it be counted in the average?

So let's assume shifts do not overlap, shift end before midnight and if an Employee doesn't work at all, doesn't influence the average.

Let's group the attendance per employee, then per day, and sum all shifts on that day. Result: per Employe, per Date, you have the total time he worked on that day

```
var WorkingTimePerDatePerEmployee = myDbContext.Attendencies
    // make groups of attendencies for the same Employee
    .GroupBy(attendancy => employee.Id,

    // the attendancies in the group are all for the same Employee
    (employeeId, attendanciesForThisEmployeeId) => new
    {
        EmployeeId = employeeId,

        AttendanciesGroupedByDate = attendanciesForThisEmployeeId
            // group by same Date:
            .GroupBy(attendancy2 => attendancy2.Date,
            (date, sameDateAttendancies => new
            {
               Date = date
               TotalWorkingHoursOnDate = sameDateAttendancies
                  // per attendancy select CheckOut - CheckIn = working time per shift
                  .Select(sameDateAttendancy => sameDateAttendancy.Checkout - sameDateAttendancy.Checkin)
                  // sum all shifts on this date
                  .Sum(),
            }),
    });
```

So now you have per EmployeeId, for all the Dates he worked. All you have to do is sum all shifts and divide it by the number of worked days.